# How to modify CMakeList file for a project in kdevelop

Tags: c++, cmake, kdevelop

I am making a project in kdevelop in Ubuntu 14.04. My project has some files such as

```
main.cpp
function1.cpp
function2.cpp

function1.h
function2.h
function_api.h
```

Note that `function_api.h` file (do not have `function_api.cpp`)

In `main.cpp`, I will include `function1.h` and `function2.h` such as

```
#include "function1.h"
#include "function2.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Meanwhile, the function1.cpp will include its header and `function_api.h`

```
#include "function1.h"
#include "function_api.h"
```

And function2.cpp only inlcude its header such as

```
#include "function2.h"
```

My question is how to modify the CMakeList to build my project above. Currently, my CMakeList is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(testProj)

add_executable(main_ex main.cpp)

install(TARGETS main_ex RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

Sorry if it is basic question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_executable( main_ex main.cpp function1.cpp function2.cpp)
```

is sufficient, if you have stringent requirements please tell me and I'll update the answer :)

EDIT:

```
add_executable( main_f1 mainf1.cpp function1.cpp)
```

Comment: Thank you. It work well. I just have small related question that is "Assume that the class function1 has one function, I want to make a execute file for that class such as func1. Because I can call it from terminal with some arguments. Is it possible to make execute for function1 and another execute  for function2. Currently, it only has main_ex of main.cpp

Comment: you need a different main including only "function1.h", see the edit, you can add as many executables as you like in the same CMake file :)

Comment: Thank for your help. :)